Calculate the solubility product of calomel using potential?
How do you calculate the solubility product of calomel if the potential of the calomel electrode (Hg2Cl2 / Hg / KCl) is given against a standard hydrogen cell with E = 3.22 V. A 1M KCl solution was used and the chloride ions have an activity of 0.6. I set up the Nernst equation so that the potential only depends on the chloride ions. If the solubility product is rearranged according to the chloride ions and inserted into the Nernst equation, a strange result comes out.
My solution:


You need to show your working. What is this "strange result"?

Strange results may be right. For example, $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ solubility product is rather low : about $\pu{10^{-18}}$. This value can be considered as "strange".

The potential of the calomel electrode against SHE is supposed to be $\pu{0.281 V}$ when $\ce{KCl}$ concentration is $\pu{1 M}$. The given value in the question is way high. Is that a mistake?

This is not a mistake. But you have to use the activity of the chloride ions, not the concentration.

The rection you have setup is incorrect as you cannot just assume activity of electron to be $1$. Since, the calomel half-reaction is set against SHE, the reaction will be 
At cathode: $\ce{Hg2Cl2(aq) + 2e- <=> 2Hg(s) + 2Cl-(aq)}$ 
At anode: $\ce{H2(g) <=> 2H+(aq) + 2e-}$ 
To a give a net reaction as: $\ce{Hg2^{2+}(aq) + H2(g) <=>2Hg(s) + 2H+(aq)}$ 
The equilibrium constant is:
$$
K_{\mathrm{eq}}=\frac{a(\ce{Hg})^2\ a(\ce{H+})^2}{a(\ce{Hg2^{2+}})\ a(\ce{H2})} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
The solubilty product reaction is: $\ce{Hg2Cl2(s) <=> Hg2^{2+}(aq) + 2Cl-(aq)}$ where,
$$
K_{\mathrm{sp}}=\frac{a(\ce{Hg2^{2+}})\ a(\ce{Cl-})^2}{a(\ce{Hg2Cl2})}=a(\ce{Hg2^{2+}})\ a(\ce{Cl-})^2 \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
as $a(\ce{Hg2Cl2_{(s)}})=1$ (by definition).
Rearranging $\eqref{2}$ and substituting in $\eqref{1}$ to get
$$\begin{align}
K_{\mathrm{eq}} &= \frac{a(\ce{H+})^2}{a(\ce{H2})}\cdot\frac{a(\ce{Cl-})^2}{K_{\mathrm{sp}}}\\ \tag{3}\label{3}
\log{(K_{\mathrm{eq}})} &= -2\ \mathrm{pH}-\log{(K_{\mathrm{sp}})}+\log{\left[\frac{a(\ce{Cl-})^2}{a(\ce{H2})}\right]} 
\end{align}$$
as $a(\ce{Hg_{(s)}})=1$ and $\mathrm{pH}=-\log{a(\ce{H+})}$ 
From equilibrium condition:
$$
\log{(K_{\mathrm{eq}})}=\frac{nFE^{\circ}}{RT\ln{(10)}} \tag{4}\label{4}
$$
where $n=2$ 
From $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{4}$
$$
\log{(K_{\mathrm{sp}})}=-\frac{nFE^{\circ}}{RT\ln{(10)}}-2\ \mathrm{pH}+\log{\left[\frac{a(\ce{Cl-})^2}{a(\ce{H2})}\right]}
$$
So you will need both $\mathrm{pH}$ and pressure of $\ce{H2}$, i.e, $a(\ce{H2})$ to correctly determine $K_{\mathrm{sp}}$
